# Explaining Spin(3)

Tags: lie-groups, rotations, quaternions, visualization, spherical-geometry

I’m going to discuss the action of [Spin(3)](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Spin_group) on Euclidean vectors. This thing has several alternative names: [“versors”/“rotation quaternions”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor), “quaternionic adjoint representation”, [“quaternion action on vectors”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988969/quaternion-spinor-relationship), [“weight-1 irrep of SU(2)”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2)), but I did not encounter visualization concepts that are illustrative and correct simultaneously.

My best effort to show both the group operation (as composition of great-circle arcs) and its action (also on the unit sphere) resulted in

[image: unit sphere in stereographic projection]
(rendered from [File:Spin_180,60.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Spin_180,60.svg)).

This concept can be technically improved (made into animation or even an interactive applet), but tracing 3D rotations in the form of motions on a sphere requires some familiarity with spherical geometry. Does anybody know a better concept that can **explain Spin(3),** presumedly **using a common 3D geometrical intuition?** It is expected really to show Spin(3) elements in some way and how to multiply them, not only substantiate the π<sub>1</sub>(SO(3)) thing.

Comment: Have you looked at [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_entanglement) or [_Gravitation_](http://books.google.com/books/about/Gravitation.html?id=w4Gigq3tY1kC) by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler?

Comment: @Jack Lee: “orientation entanglement” is actually a homotopy stuff, i.e. π₁(SO(3)), without a realistic geometry. Thanks for the book link anyway.